# DRF Nested serializers

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I'm kind of confused in writing the nested serializer in django rest framework. If I have tow models `Account` and `UserProfile`. In which `UserProfile` is ForeignKey to `Account` and when writing serilaizer should I call `UserProfile Serializer` in `Account's Serializer` or call `Account Serilaizer` in `UserProfile Serializer`.
#Models.py

```
Class Account (AbstractBaseUser):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=100, unique=True
```

```
Class USerProfile(models.Model): 
    user = models.ForeignKey(Account, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    address_line_1 = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    address_line_2 = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    phone = models.IntegerField(null=True)
```

And in writing serializer I'm confused. So please explain to me in detail how to write nested serializer.

#Serializers.py

```
class AccountSerializer(ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Account
        fields = ["first_name", "last_name", "email", "password"]
        extra_kwargs = {
            "password": {"write_only": True},
        }
```

```
class UserProfileSerializer(ModelSerializer):
    user = AccountSerializer()
    class Meta:
        model = UserProfile
        fields = "__all__"

    def create(self, validated_data):
      #Didn't write the logics here as of now.
      return super().create(validated_data)
```

So Is this this correct way to write nested serializer?

Comment: that's depend on requirements but here you have to call UserProfileSerializers because you are using AccountSerializer in UserProfileSeralizers.

Comment: I didnt understand. Can you explain a little about requirements you talked about

Comment: Requirements would be like that if you make an API and in requirements, Front-end needs (first_name, last_name, email) in UserSerializer. so you have to nested it and send it separate separate fields like that
first_name = serializers.Charfield(source=user.first_name, read_only=True) etc

Comment: Im just asking what is the correct way to write nested serializer. The way I have implemented or other way around

Comment: yeah it is. but if i say that i dont want whole serializers just want first_name or last_name then u have to get like this first_name = serializers.Charfield(source=user.first_name, read_only=True) and add field name in Meta fields

Comment: Okay thanks a lot and how can i learn deeply about django rest framework serialization. Official docs is kinda weird for me

Comment: this is depend upon on practice if you want to make strong ORM and logics then i will guide you how to make strong ORM and so on. 
and offical docs kinda weird me also hahha. but sometimes it will helpful to me. 
if you want to connect with me you can add me on social media

Comment: It would be really helpful. Can you share me details on where can i reach you

Comment: linkedin, instagram?

Comment: Text me your id on both insta and linkedin

Comment: tanv33r_ahmad[instagram]
Tanveer Ahmad[linkdin]

Comment: search on it instagram

Comment: https://testdriven.io/blog/drf-serializers/

Make yourself a coffee. Take a deep breath, and just read this carefully. 

Create new project and play with serialiers in one endpoint with multiple models that are related. :)